# Generate many PDF without reload the page with wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I would know how generate many PDF with wicked_pdf without reload the page,
My function not render a PDF view but it direct download as attachement

In my view the user select a template and download it but if i want change the template and download again i must reload the page

My form in the view:

```
<%= form_tag preview_path(@document, format: :pdf), method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(@templates, "id", "code"), include_blank: true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Download" %>
<% end %>
```

How i respond in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf do
            render pdf: "Labels " + @template.code,
            template: "documents/preview.pdf.erb",
            layout: 'layouts/pdf.html.erb',
            disposition: 'attachment', /* DIRECT DOWNLOAD */
            locals: {:document => @document},
            show_as_html: false,
            margin:  {   top:               @template.top_margin,                     # default 10 (mm)
              bottom:            @template.bottom_margin,
              left:              @template.left_margin,
              right:             @template.right_margin },
              paper_size: @template.paper_size
            end
          end
        end
```

Comment: What would this template be? The css? You have several different pages to generate the same infomação this?

Comment: The template definine the margins of the pdf @ElisBresciani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should solve a problem it with another way:

1. Use [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), as you're can going to hang up your server.
2. Generate the pdf from [AJAX call](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax).
3. Open new tab after server response `window.open(ajax_result.url);`